# Strange selection behaviour from 2.8 to 2.79b

Tags: modeling

I would like to know why this happens.

[image]

As you can see in the image, I create an object in Blender 2.8.

Then, I copy and paste into Blender 2.79b, if I enter edit mode in 2.79 and select a face or everithing in vertex selection, the selection should be orange, but its like it was a problem with normals or maybe Blender 2.8 uses another kind of polygons that other type of software does not recognize at all?

Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: 2.79b to 2.8 should work fine, the otherway around is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of incompatibility between the two versions.

Blender 2.80 differs from 2.79 a lot. The two versions are not 100% compatible. You should not work in 2.79 with data saved or made in 2.80 or you will experience some issues, like for example this what you are seeing in this case.

If you only need to get simple geometry made in 2.80 to work in 2.79, you can export the models in some other format like .obj and import them to 2.79. It will work fine this way. However if you needed to export more complex things like materials, normal data, animation, rigs and other things you may experience a lot more problems and it might not be possible/practical to solve those. It is best to choose a version and stick with it in one project.